# How do you add text to the end of a cell in Excel

Tags: worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2007

I am wanting to add the same text to the end of about 10,000 cells, but I don't want to go through and manually type it in on every cell.

So basically, I want to:

```
A1        A5
text      =A1+"file"
          textfile
```

So in cell A5, it would look like "textfile".

That formula is incorrect though, I get `#VALUE!`

Is there any way I could do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two options:

`=concatenate(expression1, expression2, ...)`
or
`=expression1 & expression2 & ...`
The result will be the same from either of them.

If you wish to format any of the expressions then have a look into `TEXT(expression,format)`
which allows the same as `Custom` inside `Format cell` *(<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd>)*.

**NOTE:** as always the `,` between expressions may be `;` or something else depending on your locale and thus Excel settings.
Also note: if you have a localized version of Excel `concatenate` will be e.g. `sammanfoga` (Swedish).

Comment: Brilliant, thanks. I did: `=concatenate(A1,file)` and that worked.